# Actionbarsherlok Manifest file error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have installed Android V4.0 and V3.2 SDK in my machine, when i try to create a project in my eclips it says Manifest file not found.
Manifest file is not at all getting generated. Normal android projects are getting created properly but if i create a project by pointing to ABS lib, it fails..

I have tried almost all the possible steps like, setting compiler version to 1.6, restarting etc...i'm sure i have latest ADT..

Kindly help me, what is the reason causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get from git: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

File > Import > Projects from git > Clone > URI: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock.git > Next > Finish

Comment: Hi marckajuo, is this action lib, what is that available in there site  ?

Comment: It is the library ABS, just follow what I said and its gonna work

Comment: Please tell me steps once, after unzipping we need to point to libraries folder correct ? Then we have to press next, select android 4.0 right, then min SDK version should be 14 right.. And activity option will be uncheck correct

Comment: its the hardest way, import the project from git like I said, you dont need to download the zip file, just make the steps above and the library will appear in your workspace.

Comment: "Projects from git", option is not present in my eclips.. but "project from cvs is present", should we have to install a plugin?

Comment: Yes, Go to Help > Install new software > http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates > Select all > Next > Finish

Comment: @ Marckaraujo, thanks i will try and update u once it get works

Comment: but we need to set java compiler version to 1.6

Answer (score 0):

You are probably giving eclipse the incorrect project source folder. Check out this [**tutorial**](http://youtu.be/4GJ6yY1lNNY) to correctly install ActionBarSherlock

Comment: Yes, I followed similar steps